# Cannot install pyaudio, gcc error

Tags: python, pyaudio

Trying to install pyaudio with instructions [per here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/):

```
$ git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
$ cd pyaudio
$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from src/_portaudiomodule.c:28:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1161:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/features.h:215:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

What's going wrong in my installation?

Comment: gcc can't find the PortAudio header files, did you install the PortAudio dev package (e.g. `apt-get install libportaudio-dev` for ubuntu)? As a side note, at least in ubuntu pyaudio is already in the repository for both python 2 and 3, and can be installed via `apt-get install python(3)-pyaudio`.

Comment: Possible cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921947/pyaudio-installation-error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1?rq=1

Comment: what worked for me is Cerin's comment in AI_ROBOT's answer. Using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 63):

Sorry about the inappropriate answer last time, I will post the solution of the question. It might be helpful for Ubuntu distributions.

1. First we need to install portaudio modules: `sudo apt-get install libasound-dev`
2. Download the portaudio archive from: http://files.portaudio.com/download.html
3. Unzip the archive: `tar -zxvf [portaudio.tgz]`
4. Enter the directory, then run: `./configure && make`
5. Install: `sudo make install`
6. And finally: `sudo pip install pyaudio`
7. Check the version of pyaudio, it should be `0.2.9`

Comment: You don't need to download tarballs. You can just do `sudo apt-get install libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0`

Comment: @Cerin, That actually didn't work for me, so I had to follow the tarball instructions, so it's working.

Comment: @alex What OS are you on? It worked fine for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Cerin, 16.04 as well, for some reason the apt-get method couldn't locate the package. There was also a seg-fault somewhere in there as well, I think when I did apt-get update. That's probably a different issue that I'm going to have to figure out eventually. But I did manage to get the portaudio working from the tar file.

Comment: Thanks. As yum has restricted only for local repo, for centos this solution worked me.

Comment: @Cerin Works fine on Ubuntu 18.04 as well

Comment: In case you can't install libasound-dev just follow look at that link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-lib/+bug/264534

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libav-tools
sudo pip install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 21):

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio worked perfecly. thanks. 02/2022

Answer (score 13):

Install 2 things,

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev python-pyaudio
```

and then,

```
pip install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 7):

For Centos7:

```
sudo yum install -y portaudio-devel
sudo pip install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 6):

**For Windows :**

Install using pip:

```
 python -m pip install pyaudio
```

if pip is not already bundled with your installation of Python, get it [here](http://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/).

**For Mac OS X :**

Use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install the prerequisite portaudio library, then install PyAudio using pip:

```
 brew install portaudio
 pip install pyaudio
```

pip will download the `PyAudio` source and build it for your version of Python.

**For Debian/Ubuntu :**

Use the package manager to install `PyAudio`:

```
 sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio
```

If the latest version of PyAudio is not available, install it using pip:

```
pip install pyaudio
```

For better isolation from system packages, consider installing PyAudio in a virtual environment

**PyAudio Source :**

Source is available for download at the Python Package Index (PyPI): [here!](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAudio)

Or clone the git repository:

```
git clone https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
```

credits: [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#downloads) and [GitHub:Speech_Recognition](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/README.rst)

Answer (score 3):

- First we need to install portaudio modules: sudo apt-get install
  libasound-dev
- Download the portaudio archive from:
  http://portaudio.com/download.html
- Unzip the archive: `tar -zxvf [portaudio.tgz]`
- Enter the directory, then run: `./configure && make`
- Install: `sudo make install`
- And Then: `sudo pip install pyaudio`
- Update & Upgrade the system to fix all broken libraries
- `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg# libav-tools
sudo pip install pyaudio
```

as sayantan ghosh told (in my case, it's error with libav-tools) and

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio
```

as Aaron told, then pip install pyaudio

these steps works for me, Im in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

this is work for me

```
sudo apt-get install libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0
```

After that run this command

```
pip install pyaudio --user
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using kali linux 2.0, do as follows:

```
apt-get install portaudio19-dev python-pyaudio
```

then:

```
pip install pyaudio
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Download PyAudio from the link below:
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
Then, install this file using the command:

```
pip install (complete filepath)
```

Example:

```
pip install C:\Users\(Username)\Downloads\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

On Manjaro(Arch Linux)  ***sudo pacman -S python-pyaudio***

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while getting pyaudio working in an alpine linux container (python:3.9-alpine).

There were some additional packages to install in this case. I'll post what I had to do in case it's useful for someone.

```
apk add --no-cache py3-pyaudio portaudio-dev gcc musl-dev
pip install pyaudio
```

The pyaudio pip install needs gcc and also the dev files included in musl-dev package.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolved PyAudio error after a long search

Hope this can help someone.

First you find the python version using  :  python `--version` (check both Pycharm and JupyterLab as I had 3.7.6 and 3.10.4 different version and move to correct directory - I pasted the same version whl file in same directory "may be there is another way of doing it - suggestions welcome" )

Once this file is placed in the same directory - "**PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl**" you can use `pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` directly

Other findings :

In case the version and file not matching you will get this error

> ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win32.whl is not a supported wheel
> on this platform.

simple "`pip install pyaudio`" will not work (As read on internet its not working beyond 3.6)

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer - For Linux
terminal command

1. Run `pip install wheel`
2. Download this `https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition`
   Inside above-mentioned folder
3. Run `pip install ./third-party/WHEEL_FILENAME`
   Here Choose your WHEEL from `https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/tree/master/third-party`

mine was `(Linux) - PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz`

Then Finally Run:
`pip install ./third-party/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz` (replace `pip` with `pip3` if using Python 3)

Answer (score -3):

try this command pip install PyAudio

Comment: Welcome to SO! This solution was already mentioned in several answers ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57947026/6682517)).