# Gcc error, No such file or directory "Python.h" -- installing pyAudio on centOS7

Tags: python-3.x, centos7, pyaudio, portaudio

I have python 3.6.8 installed on CentOS7 and I'm trying to install pyaudio with

> sudo python3.6 -m pip install pyaudio

This format worked to install a number of other things right beforehand, but if I try to use it here i get the following error

```
src/_portaudiomodule.c:28:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

pip install pyaudio yeilds the same results

I have read the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023131/cannot-install-pyaudio-gcc-error) but I still cannot figure it out

Any advice in installation? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

It looks like `pyaudio` is compiling some C code who require `Python.h`, to fix your issue check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768/9799292

> (also, "pip install pyaudio" prints "bash: pip: command not found")

To fix this try to install pip by running this command

```sh
sudo yum install python3-pip
```

Comment: I got the python3-devel installed and the pip issue resolved but I'm struggling with portaudio.h now... When I do sudo yum install portaudio or portaudio-dev or -devel or portaudio19-dev it says it can't find the package