# PyAudio install error : Failed building wheel

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to install pyaudio but I am getting the following error. I am using windows 10. I have tried solution given in multiple other answers but they were not working for me. I am following a tutorial from YouTube.

code :

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os

r=sr.Recognizer()


engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice' , voices[1].id)



def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def takecommand():
    
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening.....")
        r.pause_threshold=1
        o=r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Wait for few moments")
        query=r.recognize_google(o,language="en-in")
        print("user said ", query)
    except Exception as e :
        print(e)
        speak("Say that Again Please ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wishme()
    takecommand()

    while True :
        wishme()
        query = takecommand().lower()

        if"wikipedia" in query:
            speak("Searching in wikipedia")
            query=query.replace("wikipedia" ,"")
            results=wikipedia.summary(query,sentences=2)
            speak("According to wikipedia ")
            speak(results)
            print(results)

        elif"open youtube" in query:
            speak("opening Boss")
            webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
        elif "open google" in query:
            speak("opening Boss")
            webbrowser.open("google.com")

        elif "open code"in query:
            speak("opening Boss")
            codepath = "C:\\Users\\Murali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe"
            os.startfile(codepath)

        elif "open chrome"in query:
            speak("opening Boss")
            chromepath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
            os.startfile(chromepath)
```

[image: This image when I use pipwin]

[image: This image when I use pip]

edit1 : I have tried `pip install PyAudio` as well and it did not work

[image]

Answer (score 9):

For those having this issue, if you are on a mac, then you need to install portaudio through homebrew first. On their documentation, you need to run the commands in this order:

```
brew install portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

I was able to resolve the issue by running the following commands:
`sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev`
Then...
`pip install pyaudio`

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this error when attempting to install a package requiring `pyaudio` on the M1 architecture macOS platform.

Looking at the [pyaudio installation instructions](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/), the macOS version of the pyaudio Python library requires `portaudio`, an additional package that can be installed using homebrew.

I already had the brew package manager installed but, if you don't, follow [these instructions](https://brew.sh/) to install homebrew.

Then the following should work:

```
brew install portaudio
pip3 install pyaudio
```

This fixed the problem for me.

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851379/how-to-install-pyaudio-on-mac-using-python-3#33851618) covers very similar content and might also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Please try pip installing it with this spelling :

```
pip install PyAudio
```

If it doesn't work, download the files from this page  [PyAudio](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/), then cd into that directory and use this command `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the PyAudio wheel from [Here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
Just search for PyAudio using `Ctrl + F` in this site and download the one, that is compatible with your PC. Further, put it in the directory where you have rest of your modules/libraries saved during the installation of Python on your Windows. Hope it helps! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can install it with Anaconda:

```bash
conda install PyAudio
```

what it has done is downloading the two library with those version:
**pyaudio-0.2.11**

**portaudio-19.6.0**

you can install them with pip and I think you can install the pyaudio version only:

```bash
pip install pyaudio==0.2.11
pip install portaudio==19.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue doing this:

```
pip install pipwin 
pipwin install pyaudio
```

(credits: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/iq8t3o/cant_install_pyaudio/)

Answer (score 0):

From: [Cannot install pyaudio, gcc error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023131/cannot-install-pyaudio-gcc-error)

First try a simple suggestion of:

sudo apt-get install libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0

I had already done the following slightly longer procedure below, which worked for me (on Debian), so didn't try the quicker approach shown above.

1. First we need to install portaudio modules: sudo apt-get install libasound-dev
2. Download the portaudio archive from: http://files.portaudio.com/download.html
3. Unzip the archive: tar -zxvf [portaudio.tgz]
4. Enter the directory, then run: ./configure && make
5. Install: sudo make install
6. And finally: sudo pip install pyaudio
7. Start Python, then to confirm it worked: import pyaudio