# pyttsx not working OsError Could not load libespeak but espeak is installed

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx3, espeak

when i try to use pyttsx3/4 it gives me an error that:
`Could not load libespeak-ng.so.1 or libespeak.so.1
to install espeak on linux, run:
sudo apt-get install -y espeak-ng ffmpeg alsa-utils

Process ended with exit code 0.`

but i installed espeak per sudo apt install but error presisits. espeak works when i try it in Terminal.

any ideas how to solve this ?

i tried to install espeak ,libespeak,/-ng same error some one sayid i shold install pyaudio but this gives my the error: `Failed to build PyAudio ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyAudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects Process returned with code 1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711732/pyaudio-install-error-failed-building-wheel

Please check this link once it might help you solve the error.