# Pip installing Geany on Raspberry pi fails with gcc error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, geany

I am currently working on a project on my raspberry pi. I am using a couple of libraries. such as pyaudio and wave. I coded it in Pycharm and now I transferred the file to the raspberry pi and using Geany. I want to use those libraries and having a hard time installing them in Geany. On pycharm I would just install it from the settings or pip install it. How can I do it on the raspberri pi?

When I try to install using pip I get the following error:

```
 command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Open up a command prompt, install and use pip.

Comment: use a requirements.txt file , then pip install -r requirements.txt. Other solutions are virtialenv + venv-pack or pex

Comment: @kpie I tried doing that but I am getting this error. command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1.

Comment: @dre-hh I got the same error. Failed building wheel for pyaudio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135955/by-installing-pyaudio-python3-on-my-raspberry-pi-3-noobs-i-get-an-error-how

Comment: ok.. you have compiled libs. venv-pack and pex wil be not option here. as those libs  compile a c extension. you need to compile everything again on the pi as it is using an arm cpu and your computer is x86_64.  Or there is some cross-compilation tooling.

Comment: easiest would be doing pip intall same libs with a requirements.txt on the pi as it will trigger compilation. Check the above link, probably you are missing some dev c-lib on the pi, and the compilation fails. The actuall error from gcc is logged in into a file and there must be more hints printed, when just `gcc failed`

Comment: Thank you @kpie one of the answers over there worked!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation of PyAudio on Raspberry pi 3 fails with gcc error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135955/installation-of-pyaudio-on-raspberry-pi-3-fails-with-gcc-error)