# portaudio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I got the following error while trying to install pyaudio using pip3 in ubuntu 16.04:

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-mxgvewdb/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-v55chjee-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-mxgvewdb/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-v55chjee-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mxgvewdb/pyaudio/
```

Comment: You could try to install `libportaudio-dev`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyaudio installation error - 'command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921947/pyaudio-installation-error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1)

Comment: Nikolay is not a duplicate, given how that question is 7 years old and any answer provided will probably reference an old version and wont work on current OS

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This should help

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio
```

Tested on `Ubuntu 18.04`, `Python 3.7.2`, `pyaudio 0.2.11`

Added 8th of Jan 2021:

On Ubuntu 20.04 you have to use:

```
sudo apt install portaudio19-dev python3-pyaudio
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked on ubuntu 16.04. Finally it got installed after a long time.

Comment: Works for ```Ubuntu 19.10```, ```Python 3.8.0```, ```pyaudio 0.2.11``` as well.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 20:04, please use this command instead: apt install portaudio19-dev  python3-pyaudio

Answer (score 5):

For MacOS (Intel/Apple Silicon):

**Step 1:**

```
brew install portaudio
```

**Step 2:**

```
brew --prefix portaudio
```

The output provided from the above command, will be required in *Step 3*, which will look something similar to `/opt/homebrew/opt/portaudio`

**Step 3:**

Create .pydistutils.cfg in your home directory

```
sudo nano ~/.pydistutils.cfg
```

then paste the following in the file, save and exit

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs=<PATH FROM STEP 2>/include/
library_dirs=<PATH FROM STEP 2>/lib/
```

**Step 4:**

```
pip3 install pyaudio
```

Comment: 'pip3 install pyaudio
fails src/_portaudiomodule.c:31:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found

Comment: @SimonFakir More info is needed, OS version, platform (Intel/Apple Silicon)?

Answer (score 5):

For Windows, 
here's what I've been going through...

**There're several ways to install PortAudio**

- vcpkg, https://vcpkg.info/port/portaudio
- winget, https://winget.run/pkg/intxcc/pyaudio
- Or, manually build from source and install manually

  1. download source, http://files.portaudio.com/download.html
  2. build with cmake, with the matching *compiler(msvc/mingw)* and *arch(x64/x86)* to your Python
  3. put "`portaudio.h`" into python-include directory, e.g. `c:\Python38-32\include\`
  4. put "`portaudio.lib` into python-lib directory, e.g. `c:\Python38-32\libs`

**Arrh!**
the "min()" macro in pyaudio's soucefile `_portaudiomodule.c` is troublesome, comment it out manually

- `pip install pyaudio --no-clean`
- find `_portaudiomodule.c` in the temp directory and manually comment-out the "min()" macro
   e.g. `c:\Temp\pip-install-yysb8bme\pyaudio_c92585\src\_portaudiomodule.c`
- `pip install` from that directory
  e.g. `pip install c:\Temp\pip-install-yysb8bme\pyaudio_c92585\`

**Or,3rd party wheels**

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59594881/3353857)  said:

> `pip install pipwin`
> `pipwin install pyaudio`

Comment: This worked for me on windows 10, thanks!

Comment: I could not find the min() macro in _portaudiomodule.c ? Could you give some more details here?

Comment: @SimonFakir There might be several conflicting copy of "min()". Therefore, I have to remove it manually in my last trail. If you can't find it, that's fine. Congratulations, no conflict!

Answer (score 2):

For Centos7/RHEL:

```sh
yum install portaudio-devel alsa-lib-devel portaudio
pip install pyaudio --user
```

Answer (score 1):

For Arch/Manjaro/EndeavourOS/Parabola/Frugalware2​/Chakra:

```
sudo pacman -Sy portaudio python-pyaudio
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: One doesn't have to install `python-pyaudio` globally. It can be installed per python environment.