# pyaudio not installing on cmd

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio, python-3.7

I tried to install pyaudio through cmd using "pip install pyaudio" initially it gave me a c++ 14.0 error which i was eventually able to solve but after that another error has showed up. 
I use python 3.7 and my system runs on windows 10

Below is the error that shows up on cmd.

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pyaudio
    Collecting pyaudio
    Using cached 
 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio



Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\FM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hybhd5fp\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\FM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-77sivvg_ --python-tag cp37:



running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\FM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hybhd5fp\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\FM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ajqph_xl\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\fm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\FM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hybhd5fp\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\FM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ajqph_xl\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python package installation issues: PyAudio, PortAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyaudio+pip

Comment: https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/ states that PyAudio is supported on Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6 (notably 3.7 is omitted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above (on the question): the official site for PyAudio ( http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/ ) states that PyAudio 0.2.11 is supported on Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6 (notably 3.7 is omitted).

I have just confirmed that I am able to successfully install PyAudio==0.2.11 via pip on Python 3.6, but that my installation fails with error C1083 `Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h'` when trying to install PyAudio==0.2.11 via pip on Python 3.7.

In order to install PyAudio==0.2.11, you must use Python 3.6.  Otherwise, you must wait for a new version of PyAudio to be released.