# I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyaudio

I have a Windows 10 PC and I want to install pyaudio to use it with my chatbot, powered by chatterbot.

I tried 2 different ways to install pyaudio.

The first way is doing this on the command prompt:

```
python -m pip install PyAudio
```

This is the result:

```
   C:\Users\Waaberi>python -m pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Waaberi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Waaberi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e5le61j0\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Waaberi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-adj3zivl\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\Waaberi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Waaberi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e5le61j0\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Waaberi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-adj3zivl\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Waaberi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e5le61j0\PyAudio\
```

The second way is entering this command:

```
python pip install python-pyaudio
```

and it does nothing.

Comment: Did you read the error message from the first command, specifically the part that says "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're also going to need to [install PortAudio](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/tutorial_start.html).

Comment: How to install PortAudio?

Comment: installing the vc++ lib is annoying because i have a higer version installed already. such as `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable(x86)`. i don't want to uninstall higher version first.

Comment: Related to this, I tried a `pip install pyaudio` using Python 3.10.11 and it successfully installed from a cached wheel (I'd tried this before somewhere?) but I can't seem to `import pyaudio` in VSCode. Anyone know what the library is called?

Comment: The specific library being installed is **not relevant** to the problem described; this error is common to many attempted installations and has a common cause - closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 186):

The [answer by Agalin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52284344/4999991) is already great and I just want to explain it in a step by step format for a novice like myself:

- find your Python version by `python --version` mine is `3.7.3` for example
- the easiest way to check either you have 64 or 32 Python just open it in the terminal:

- find the appropriate `.whl` file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio), for example mine is `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`, and download it.
- go to the folder where it is downloaded for example `cd C:\Users\foobar\Downloads`
- install the `.whl` file with `pip` for example in my case:

```
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Hi Foad,
I have followed your steps and went to that folder and ran like this,
C:\Users\harnish.shah\Downloads>pip3 install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
even I had tried with upgrading pip also but can't install. Can you please help with this?

Comment: @HarnishShah I don't think it has anything to do with the `pip upgrade`. I think you either don't have admin rights on your device, or you haven't followed the first two steps correctly.

Comment: Worked also on pycharm when I cloned the file to the project folder and then run the pip3 install

Comment: [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve “error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57731053/5033247)

Comment: @HanishShalah You have to match the wheel to your platform. The file you tried is for Python 3.8 64-bit. Check your Python version as described in the answer and try again with the appropriate `.whl` file.

Comment: Confirmed this works on Python 3.9 Windows 10.

Answer (score 161):

First run your IDE or CMD as **Administrator** and run the following commands:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Comment: I had a handshake error for whatever reason. So I used Agalins answer. Still upvoted this one.

Comment: yes, this should be the accepted answer. I saw the multiple StackOverflow posts which have the same answer but none of them mentioned about running the terminal as admin. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Thank you so much it takes two hours for me to reach your answer. Waste a lot of time searching. You are a life saver. Thanks again.

Comment: This is the easiest way !!

Comment: Why does it always take at least 2 hours to find a perfect answer of just 2 lines ?

Comment: Doesn't work for MacOs

Comment: @Aishwaryakabadi It's for Windows.

Comment: It didn't work for me on windows 11 neither.

Comment: @The_spider worked for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 35):

There is no wheel (prebuilt package) for Python 3.7 on Windows (there is one for Python 2.7 and 3.4 up to 3.6) so you need to prepare build environment on your PC to use this package. Easier would be finding the wheel for 3.7 as some packages are quite hard to build on Windows.

Christoph Gohlke (University of California) hosts Windows wheels for most popular packages for nearly all modern Python versions, including latest PyAudio. You can find it here: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) (download can be quite slow). After download, just type `pip install <downloaded file here>`.

There is no difference between `python -m pip install`, and `pip install` as long as you're using default installation settings and single python installation. `python pip` actually tries to run file `pip` in the current directory.

Edit. See the `pipwin` comment for automated way of using Mr Gohlke's libs . Note that I've not used it myself and I'm not sure about selecting different package flavors like vanilla and mkl versions of `numpy`.

Comment: [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve “error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57731053/5033247)

Answer (score 17):

Use `Conda` instead of `pip`.
It works perfectly

```
conda install PyAudio
```

Comment: Note that (Ana)conda has a license agreement. So depending on your context, this might not be an option.

Answer (score 10):

you may need to try

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

you may also need to install Visual Studio 2015, and remember to choose to install Visual C++ 14.0
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Answer (score 9):

For some reason pip does not work,
instead you could try first installing "pipwin" if you don't already have it
Open a cmd and paste this:

```
pip install pipwin
```

and **then** install PyAudio using:

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

It should work. But if you don't want to use pipwin.. just install it and then uninstall it afterwards by simply using:

```
pip uninstall pipwin
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is **pyaudio** does not have wheels for python **3.7** just try some lower version like **3.6**
then install `pyaudio`

It works

Answer (score 4):

If you have anaconda install than you just need to use command: `conda install PyAudio`.

In order to execute this command you must set the`PYTHONPATH` environment variable in anaconda.

Comment: You can include code examples when answering questions

Comment: Why not edited https://stackoverflow.com/a/62323213/5033247?

Answer (score 4):

You should install python 3.6 version because python 3.7 version doesn't support pyaudio
*1 step* : Then download the .whl file
according to your python version and the configuration of your machine in your python folder which is newly installed. For me it is python 3.6 and 64 bit machine. Download the file from here
([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/))
*2 step* : run your cmd and type " pip install *your downloaded file name here*  "

Comment: [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve “error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57731053/5033247)

Answer (score 2):

Seems PyAudio is supported by Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6.  Refer https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Please suggest if there is any alternate way to install PyAudio on Python 3.8.2

Answer (score 1):

You should just install python 3.6. I tried it and it worked. Just install that version of python and just do the normal download process (`pip install pyaudio`).

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error as :

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

As, said by @Agaline, i download the outside wheel from this [Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).

If your is `Python 3.7` then try to `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` and use command as, go to the download directroy and:

`pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` and it works.

Comment: [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve “error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57731053/5033247)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.7.3 and Windows 10 64-bit machine then try the following command. 
Go to the download folder and Install following command:

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

and it should work.

Comment: First, you should download the whl for that

Answer (score 0):

For PyCharm use the Terminal:
pip install pipwin
pipwin install PyAudio <-- Remember the capital letters

Answer (score 0):

Try following command for MacOS using python 3.8.2
install Homebrew on your terminal

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Visual Studio Code terminal

1.`brew install portaudio`

2.`pip install pyaudio`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this damn problem on Linux **Fedora-36**.

```
sudo dnf install portaudio-devel
```

After that, portaudio, portaudio-devel and alsa-lib-devel packages were installed.

Then Kindly;

```
pip install pyaudio
```

All the problem went away with my execution.

Comment: Nice answer, but this is for Windows. Hopefully it helps someone, but otherwise this isn't directly related to the question...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are building something requiring input from the user and also the keyboard. You will need various libraries, I will list all of them directly from the source...

```
!apt-get install -y portaudio19-dev libasound-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0
!pip install pyaudio wave keyboard pydub
```

It installs various dependencies for `pyaudio` which may hinder the installation of `pyaudio`.

Comment: Thank you for submitting an answer! However, it looks like your suggestion is intended for a Linux system using apt, whereas the OP is looking for help on the Windows platform.

Comment: Then replace apt-get install -y with pip install.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue but solved it by using Ubuntu.

1. `python -m pip install pyaudio`
2. Install sudo, apt-get and then install homebrew &/ linuxbrew on your linux subsystem using Ubuntu.
3. The latest version supports ubuntu.
4. `brew install portaudio`
5. Make sure you have python/python3 installed on the terminal
6. Make sure the current location is added as path in your virtual computer's path in environment Variable.
7. `brew link portaudio`

Comment: your answer is to change operating system?