# Can't install PyAudio in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, installation, pyaudio

I get the following ERROR while installing pyaudio

```
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-snth_fqh\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3n7dvpm8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-snth_fqh\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3n7dvpm8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-snth_fqh\pyaudio\
```

Comment: What did you not understand from the error output?  `extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ ---------------------------------------- ` Also take this StackOverflow Tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52284344/4777984

Comment: error is self explanatory

Answer (score 1):

You are missing Visual C++ from your computer. Download and install from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

and then re run the install for PyAudio.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio changed the Build Tools from being C++ specific in late 2017. Thus newer `Visual Studio` versions work in place of older versions.

You can install it using:

1.https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16
2.https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019

Windows Python needs `Visual C++` libraries installed via the SDK to build code.