# Pyaudio is not installing in Python 3.7.3 (Windows)

Tags: python

I am trying to install pyaudio in python 3.7.3 (Windows)
It is showing an error, here what it's showing :

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q7w1mmmt\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-11q1m9y5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q7w1mmmt\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-11q1m9y5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q7w1mmmt\pyaudio\
```

Answer (score 0):

`pyaudio` library needs to be compiled (or you need to download a compiled version) before you can use it. Here're some related links:

- [I can't install pyaudio on my python? How to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-my-python-how-to-do-it)
- https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/compilation.html