# Python ModuleNotFound and other

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

```
import pyttsx3 #pip install pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr #pip install speechRecognition
import datetime
import wikipedia #pip install wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# print(voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak("Good Morning!")

    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon!")

    else:
        speak("Good Evening!")

    speak("I am Jarvis Sir. Please tell me how may I help you")

def takeCommand():
    #It takes microphone input from the user and returns string output

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)
        print("Say that again please...")
        return "None"
    return query

def sendEmail(to, content):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('youremail@gmail.com', 'your-password')
    server.sendmail('youremail@gmail.com', to, content)
    server.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wishMe()
    while True:
    # if 1:
        query = takeCommand().lower()

        # Logic for executing tasks based on query
        if 'wikipedia' in query:
            speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
            speak("According to Wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)

        elif 'open youtube' in query:
            webbrowser.open("youtube.com")

        elif 'open google' in query:
            webbrowser.open("google.com")

        elif 'open stackoverflow' in query:
            webbrowser.open("stackoverflow.com")


        elif 'play music' in query:
            music_dir = 'D:\\Non Critical\\songs\\Favorite Songs2'
            songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
            print(songs)
            os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))

        elif 'the time' in query:
            strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            speak(f"Sir, the time is {strTime}")

        elif 'open code' in query:
            codePath = "C:\\Users\\Haris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe"
            os.startfile(codePath)

        elif 'email to harry' in query:
            try:
                speak("What should I say?")
                content = takeCommand()
                to = "harryyourEmail@gmail.com"
                sendEmail(to, content)
                speak("Email has been sent!")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                speak("Sorry my friend harry bhai. I am not able to send this email")
```

I am getting AttributeError. Please help me solving it. I have installed the required packages like speechrecognition, wikipedia and pyttsx3.

I am unable to download pyaudio. I am using windows operating system. refer to the error screenshot provided. It would be a great help. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14)

Comment: yes i installed mic. visual c++ 14.0 that is required

Answer (score 0):

I think pyaudio requires c++ build tools, have you installed them?

Answer (score 0):

in line 30 with sr.Microphone() as source:
takeCommand error

in line 47 query = takeCommand() .lower()
 error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).