# How to install pyaudio? pip Install pyaudio, Giving error

Tags: python, pyaudio

```
pip install pyaudio
```

Giving error,

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q34_lfl5\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q34_lfl5\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q8jvhxle\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.

```
Regards,
Neha
```

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294432/error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-in-window/66884843#66884843

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyAudio error at the time of intallation (subprocess-exited-with-error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072094/pyaudio-error-at-the-time-of-intallation-subprocess-exited-with-error)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. you should install `pyaudio` offline.
First, download the `whl` file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) then install it.

```
pip install <downloaded file here>
```

In my case:

```
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

[image: Shot]

Windows wheels are the most popular packages for nearly all modern Python versions, including the latest PyAudio.
**please attention**, you should download the version is capable with your system. If you got error like this:
`ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`
try another file until installing successfully.

**PyAudio**

```
Includes ASIO, DS, WMME, WASAPI, WDMKS support.
PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win32.whl
PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl
PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl    #this version worked for me
PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
...
```

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14/52284344#52284344) too.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to website and download the version of pyaudio as per your Python version from [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files).
- Browse the directory where the file is downloaded.
- Open command prompt there
- Type command `pip install <filename.extension>` in my case `pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
- It will install
- Comment if facing issues in above process.

Comment: if you need 32 or 64 bit whl files is not determined by the OS, but by the python version that is installed. You can have a 64 bit OS, but 32 bit python installed. Then you would need 32 bit whl files.It might also be worth to include that OP seems to have a 32 bit python 3.8 installed (see their installation directory), so you could point them to cp38 win32 whl

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubt !! I was confused with this one.

Answer (score 0):

your python version is 3.7 or obove Try

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```