# Why can't I import PyAudio?

Tags: python

I was trying to import PyAudio, but it keeps giving me an error.  Incase it is a problem with my computer, I am on Windows 64x and Python 3.9.4.  Here is the error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\alext\\Desktop\\Olive\\venv\\src\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\alext\\Desktop\\Olive\\venv\\src\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix=
         cwd: C:\Users\alext\Desktop\Olive\venv\src\pyaudio\
    Complete output (13 lines):
    running develop
    running egg_info
    creating src\PyAudio.egg-info
    writing src\PyAudio.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\PyAudio.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\PyAudio.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'src\PyAudio.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'src\PyAudio.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'src\PyAudio.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\alext\\Desktop\\Olive\\venv\\src\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\alext\\Desktop\\Olive\\venv\\src\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

If any of you know how to fix this, please let me know!  I am still learning how to read Python logs / errors!  Thank you!

Comment: you can download wheel file according to your python and windows version https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio here! and install it using pip

Comment: You can refer to this, it is almost the same, except for, it is numpy and yours is PyAudio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294432/error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-in-window/66884843#66884843

Answer (score 0):

Notice this:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Looks like you will need C++ 14.0.
I'm not sure which link will work better, but here are some that I found.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Current PyAudio PIP package is not precompiled, see list of precompiled packages [here]. For Python 3.9 it is delivered in source, it was compiled only until Python 3.6.

Compiling package from source needs Visual Studio to be installed, also even then compiling not always succeeds, so it is good to install binary precompiled package if possible.

But there is alternative source of package, [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio). Download file `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl` and install it through `python -m pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`. This package is precompiled and doesn't need Visual Studio.

Comment: Where would I put the file to install it?  I tried putting in it my project but it keeps saying that it is not a valid file.

Comment: @RaNdOm_PErsOn159 Can you please show me your console output and error message? Also try installing with `--verbose` flag, it says much more info, i.e. do `pip install --verbose filename.whl`. I think you downloaded it with error, not fully downloaded, you can try downloading it again. Also watch in your browser that it finished downloading, because that site is slow and downloads may take some time.

Comment: @RaNdOm_PErsOn159 I have Windows x64 and Python 3.9 too, and just installed this package successfully, [this is](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39kqxiW/PM@uACygoJurUJBZoJCZV1ySmJOjEFDpWJqSma9roGekZ2iom1xgbAkhyjPz4hNzU8xM9MozcrgCivKTU4uLM/PSFZKtYlKA5sUUVCYSo9MTYhFYZ35OTmpySWqKQkFicnZiemqxFcx@ruDSZJAFaaU5OZUwxwEVojrv/38A) how it looks like in my console.