# PyAudio is not supported on this platform error

Tags: pyaudio

PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

This is what it says when I type
"pip install 'file name'"

I have Python 3.8

I want to make an assistant
Please tell me, I am new.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, python 3.7+ does not have a built in wheel package. Check the answer below for a possible solution:

[This question would be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14/52284344#52284344)