# I am using python 3.9 and I can't figure out how to install pyaudio in my Windows 10

Tags: python, pyaudio, python-3.9

Currently using Visual Studio Code
Tried using **pip install pyaudio** but it simply gave an error like:

```
PS C:\Users\NIKHIL> pip install pyaudio
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is 
not writeable
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NIKHIL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yo0mmwlt\\pyaudio_d4ca14ee2a5246debede93cab086f909\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NIKHIL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yo0mmwlt\\pyaudio_d4ca14ee2a5246debede93cab086f909\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\NIKHIL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-cbxwzcr9'
       cwd: C:\Users\NIKHIL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yo0mmwlt\pyaudio_d4ca14ee2a5246debede93cab086f909\
  Complete output (9 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NIKHIL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yo0mmwlt\\pyaudio_d4ca14ee2a5246debede93cab086f909\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NIKHIL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yo0mmwlt\\pyaudio_d4ca14ee2a5246debede93cab086f909\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NIKHIL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-u900rrya\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\NIKHIL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\pyaudio'  
         cwd: C:\Users\NIKHIL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yo0mmwlt\pyaudio_d4ca14ee2a5246debede93cab086f909\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NIKHIL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yo0mmwlt\\pyaudio_d4ca14ee2a5246debede93cab086f909\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NIKHIL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yo0mmwlt\\pyaudio_d4ca14ee2a5246debede93cab086f909\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NIKHIL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-u900rrya\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\NIKHIL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command 
output.
```

please suggest a way out of this

Comment: The part of the error message which begins "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required." seems relevant.

Answer (score 14):

You can also try to install it with the .whl file.

1. Find your Python version
2. 64 or 32 bit?
3. Find the appropriate file [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
   For example, my Python version is the 3.9 64bit I would download the "PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl" file.
4. Open your CMD and go to the folder where the file is. Ex.: cd C:\Users\Miguel\Downloads
5. Install it: pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl

Hope it helped!

Comment: it is as simple as that. Stop here.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57731053/14586140) from a StackOverflow question might help, as I had the same problem and it solved the problem for me.

> First run your IDE or CMD as Administrator and run the following:
>
> ```
> pip install pipwin
> pipwin install pyaudio
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands below:

```sh
pip install pipwin

pipwin install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message it seems you require Visual C++ build tools.

The link to download that is also given within that error message.

In case the link does not work,You can download it here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

You can try this and incase errors still persist, reply to this thread.

**Upvote if it helped!**

Answer (score 1):

`PyAudio` just doesn't have the wheels for Python `3.7` or higher. If you want to use `PyAudio`, it is best to download python version `3.6.9` [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-369/).

I wish you the best
-arivvid27

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Python 3.9 and didn´t work, so I installed Python 3.8 too and pyaudio worked fine (I've double checked and downloaded both versions of pyaudio on [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)).
I still don't know why it doesn't work on 3.9.
Did it work for someone on python 3.9? If yes, let me know what did you do. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

you should use python 3.6.9 or lower