# How to install Visul Studio C++ 14.0 in Window 8.1

Tags: python, pyaudio

When I was installing pyaudio on Window 8.1 x86, and an Error came that you need to install Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 14.0 .

Error message:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.micr
osoft.com/downloads/
```

then I downloaded the installer and when i started installing, then an error came to install an update **KB2919355**

Then I downloaded **Windows8.1-KB2919355-x86.msu** 319mb file, and when I started installation then the following Error dialog came:

```
The update is not applicable to your computer.
```

I searched on various places but could not find anything.

Thank You!

Comment: Hello Prashant. Please tell us your Windows edition and build code. You can find it in your "About Your PC" section from windows search, or through the system menu in windows settings.

Comment: `When I was installing pyaudio on Window 8.1 x86` what did you actually try? Which Python version are you using?  There's no `Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 14.0`, that's probably the Visual C++ runtime version. And Windows 8.1 is out of support. The upgrade to Windows 10 is free

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14)

Comment: thanks for the help guys but i replaced that computer :-)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i downloaded wheel for pyaudio from unknown source and it workd for me