# Speech Recognition crashes when I move it to Qthread

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, speech-recognition, qthread

I have seen similar issues with sr used with python especially when having a running gui. **But there is not one question or answer that really solves my problem**. I want to run the speech recognition code in a QThread while the main thread takes care of the gui. The sr code **works fine** when it's executed in the main thread but **NOT** when I move it to QThread. After debugging, it seems that the code crashes on the the line:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
```

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

I have read that it's because I have a while True loop in my Qthread, which seems to be **wrong** because even when I remove it, it still crashes. Any idea why I'm getting this? Here's the code below:

```
# Create worker
class VoiceWorker(QThread):
    sentChat = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        
        while True:
            print("Say somethig!")
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                audio = r.listen(source)
                said = ""
                print("Got it! Now to recognize it...")
                try:
                    said = r.recognize_google(audio)
                    # self.textChanged.emit(value)
                    # self.sentChat.emit(said)
                    print(said)
                except sr.UnknownValueError:
                    print("Oops")



class Ui_OutputDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        # Create window UI
        super(Ui_OutputDialog, self).__init__()
        loadUi("./outputwindow.ui", self)

        # Create Qthread for always listening
        self.listening_worker = VoiceWorker()
        self.listening_worker.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_OutputDialog()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Okaaay so it turned out to be a missing library. "PyAudio". On my mac I had no problem installing it but on windows I had errors so I found this useful:
[I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve “error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14)