# Pyaudio not being found as a module

Tags: python, pyaudio

I have finally installed Pyaudio with the correct wheel and everything. I have confirmed its installation several times and it has been successfully installed. It is my first time using pip so I am not 100% sure about everything. When I open pycharm and import pyaudio, it cannot find it as a module. Can anyone please help? Thanks

Comment: Welcome, aidang3 to SO. Just refer the answers provided over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14?answertab=active#tab-top) once. Maybe these could help solve your problem

Comment: I already did install pyaudio. It just isn't appearing on pycharm for some reason.

Comment: Just to check if pyaudio is successfully installed on your laptop, can you kindly execute `import pyaudio` command on python IDLE. This would confirm whether this is a with pycharm or whether you have not installed it properly.

Comment: Yeah its been installed.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to help you any further. I basically use VSCode as my text editor, and things worked really well after executing the following commands `pip install pipwin` and `pipwin install pyaudio`. I can't understand why things are not working as expected for you in pycharm

Comment: Thats fine. Thank you anyways.

Comment: It is possible that you have instances of Python installed. If that happens, then `pip` from the command line may do the install to the instance you are not expecting. Do `pip --version` and see if the Python instance it reports agrees with what PyCharm thinks is the project interpreter.

Comment: Yeah thats all good too.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a pyaudio whl here: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
and type on your terminal:

```
pip install 'the name of your whl file'
```