# Not able to Run Speech Recognition Code Due to some error

Tags: python, pycharm, speech-recognition, pyaudio

This the code I wrote for speech recognition after successful installation of necessary libraries.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Please Speak: ')
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(f'Did you told: {text}')

    except:
        print('Could not understand')
```

I am not able to understand what these **horrible error means**. Repeatedly am installing pyaudio but that is not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfMdT.png)

This is the gift am getting while installing pyaudio.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNpMp.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14)

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, installing pyaudio directly through pip doesn't work. The top answer (by Foad) on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14) is what worked for me.