# How can i install pyaudio on visual studio?

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

How can i install pyaudio on visual studio

I tried
pip install pyaudio
but i'm getting error

after that i downloaded pyaudio files but not able to install them
provide me a solution

Comment: Can you post the pip command you tried and the error you got afterwards?

Comment: please post a traceback from pip's attempt to install pyaudio. Read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14)

There are many ways to do this, I will tell here two.

---

### Install `PyAudio` using `pipwin`

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

This is the simple way. If it doesn't work follow the below method.

---

### Install `PyAudio` using `wheel`

1. First check your python version.
   [image: Check python version]
2. Go to this website: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
3. Find and download the correct version of your Python wheel. Here I will choose `3.7` and `64 bit`.
4. This would be the right wheel for me: `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`
5. Open any terminal in the downloaded folder and install it with the help of this command.

`pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`

**Note:** Here instead of my wheel name, write the name of your wheel.

Reference: [pyaudio install error windows | pyaudio error microsoft visual c++ 14.0 is required](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SX6ZA8z6pFg)

Comment: I tried it but dont know why this is downloading an amd

Comment: can you tell me your python version and bit so that I can help you well

Comment: python 3.9.7  
file name which i downloaded is PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64
and after running following command in CMD C:\Users\bharat chauhan>pip install C:\Users\bharat chauhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl

i'm getting error
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'C:\\Users\\bharat'
Hint: It looks like a path. File 'C:\Users\bharat' does not exist.

Comment: You have to write the path inside the quote. Like this: `pip install "C:\Users\bharat chauhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"`
Copy and paste this command.
after that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed it....

just paste downloaded .whl file at C:\Users\bharat chauhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts & fromr here open cmd & run command pip install file name