# I have windows 11, python3.10, and I am unable to install pyaudio?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I am trying a speech recognition software and I tried installing pyaudio through unofficial python binaries, but its giving the following error when I type 'pip install PyAudio' in cmd terminal. please help I am stuck.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoZhH.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14)

Comment: Please try to paste the error from your try here in a text format instead of a picture. And if you are sharing the picture, please consider not making it a hyper link so it doesn't require clicking on the link.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.