# I am getting an error when i try to download pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am unable to download pyaudio it says I need to install the 'wheel' package in order to download it but I already have downloaded the wheel package, what should I do in order to get the package

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El2yK.png)

Comment: You need to install C++ Build Tools.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please make sure to do [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on your issue before posting a question. There are multiple existing posts on this issue on this site, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840).