# can't install pyaudio python and PyCharm

Tags: python, pyaudio

When I'm trying tutorial from internet I got this

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User>pip3 install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Requirement 'PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing c:\users\user\pyaudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl'


C:\Users\User>pip3 install pyaudio
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
      cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Program Files\Python310\include -IC:\Program Files\Python310\Include /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
      error: command 'cl.exe' failed: None
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pyaudio did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
      cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Program Files\Python310\include -IC:\Program Files\Python310\Include /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
      error: command 'cl.exe' failed: None
      [end of output]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: select message and use button `Ctrl+K` to format it. OR put message in ```  ```

Comment: did you download `PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` ? Do you have it in folder `C:\Users\User` ?

Comment: you can run `pip install` with option `-v` to see more details (`verbose`). Maybe it needs to instal compilator `C/C++` because this module may have some code in `C/C++` and it needs to compile it.

Comment: Pay attention to the early warning; "WARNING: Requirement 'PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist" - you're issuing a command that you would use if you had downloaded the wheel, but you didn't do that, or it is not in the current directory when you give the command. Either download the wheel, or use `pip3 install pyaudio`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14)