# "No Module named '_portaudio': Unable to find solution

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio, portaudio

For my computer science coursework in 6th form, I am making a python program that uses voice recognition as an input. Through research, I have found a way to do so by using the libraries called 'SpeechRecognition', and then 'PyAudio' which SR is dependant on.

The code I am having trouble with is a section that allows the user to speak into a microphone and then the program recognizes the speech and converts it into text.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
     print ("Say Something")
     audio = r.listen(source)
     print ("Audio Recieved")

     text = r.recognize_google (audio)
     print (text)
```

When I run the code in the python shell, I am getting the following response:

> ImportError: No module named '_portaudio'

After searching the internet thoroughly, I have not been able to find the missing component to PyAudio, _portaudio, which PyAudio is dependant on.

How do I fix this issue? Is there a webpage where I can find the missing element? If so, what are the installation procedures?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python package installation issues: PyAudio, PortAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio)

Comment: Yes, how did you install pyaudio, and what platform are you on? Best to use `conda` on Windows and often on Unix, too, if you need C-library-based packages like `pyaudio`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using python on windows, and I installed pyaudio using the CMD program

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the following

sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev

git clone https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git

cd pyaudio/

sudo python3 setup.py install

Comment: First line `sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev` solved for me.