# how do I solve error installing a python library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\taha shahid\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\TAHASH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2qf6m14f\\Pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\TAHASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7w0_tqr0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 "-Ic:\users\taha shahid\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include" "-Ic:\users\taha shahid\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\taha shahid\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    c:\users\taha shahid\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): note: command-line arguments:  see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\taha shahid\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\TAHASH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2qf6m14f\\Pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\TAHASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7w0_tqr0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\TAHASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2qf6m14f\Pyaudio\
```

I have installed record/records. It still gives me this error. Same was the case while installing `pycrypto` library.

Comment: Which package are you trying to install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python package installation issues: PyAudio, PortAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio)

Comment: I am trying to install Pyaudio.. And same problem occured while installing PyCrypto and Crypto libraries..