# I am using pycharm in Windows 10 and I am getting the error on pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm installing pyaudio first time and its giving error

```
(venv) C:\Users\Arsii\PycharmProjects\speechrecognition>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Arsii\PycharmProjects\speechrecognition\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Arsii\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
\\pip-install-m_rcofoh\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record
C:\Users\Arsii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4rzncnc0\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Arsii\PycharmProjects\speechrecognition\ven
v\include\site\python3.7\pyaudio:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Users\Arsii\PycharmProjects\speechrecognition\venv\incl
ude -IC:\Users\Arsii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\Arsii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC
\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\
um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\arsii\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    c:\users\arsii\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): note: command-line arguments:  see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\Arsii\PycharmProjects\speechrecognition\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Arsii\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m_rcofoh\\
pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Arsii\AppData\L
ocal\Temp\pip-record-4rzncnc0\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Arsii\PycharmProjects\speechrecognition\venv\include\site\python3.7
\pyaudio" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Arsii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m_rcofoh\pyaudio\
```

Comment: @Daniil Ryzhkov why while editing his question did you remove the fact he is issuing the command through the PyCharm console? Maybe there could be lying the solution..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python package installation issues: PyAudio, PortAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio)

Comment: Try to reinstall microsoft visual c++ 14.0 from [link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)

Comment: @GiovaLombaI I haven't removed anything, just added formatting. However, feel free to propose rollback for what you feel was removed.

Comment: @Giova well, I've improved other person edit and haven't noticed that he removed something

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov I understand, sorry if I seemed a bit rude. Some times issuing commands through pycharm console lead to strange results because of the ide implementation. To me that happend several times.