# Unable to install PyAudio in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyaudio

I am trying to install `pyaudio` on `VScode`, but this the `error message` what I am getting.

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: 'C:\Users\yaser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
>   -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\yaser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mvex6epu\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\yaser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mvex6epu\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\yaser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6tgvqtqn\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=
>            cwd: C:\Users\yaser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mvex6epu\pyaudio\
>       Complete output (17 lines):
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       running build_ext
>       building '_portaudio' extension
>       creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
>       creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
>       creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
>       D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 "-IC:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include"
>   "-IC:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include"
>   -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\ATLMFC\include -ID:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt"
>   /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c
>   /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
>       _portaudiomodule.c
>       c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\pyconfig.h(117):
>   warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
>       c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\pyconfig.h(117):
>   note: command-line arguments:  see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
>       src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
>       error: command 'D:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
>   failed with exit status 2
>       ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   'C:\Users\yaser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
>   -u
>   -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\yaser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mvex6epu\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\yaser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mvex6epu\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\yaser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6tgvqtqn\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python package installation issues: PyAudio, PortAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio)

Comment: yeah thanks soo much i solve it