# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 while installing pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

After doing `pip install pyaudio`, It started collecting the package but suddenly it displayed this error. Hope the following explains what's going on:

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\mayank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mayank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b1kw0ltr\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mayank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b1kw0ltr\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mayank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s8qn1fa4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\mayank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\mayank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b1kw0ltr\pyaudio\
```

Complete output (15 lines):

```
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\mayank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\mayank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\mayank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mayank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b1kw0ltr\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mayank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b1kw0ltr\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mayank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s8qn1fa4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\mayank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Which OS are you currently on?

Comment: https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#id9

Comment: i'am using windows 7

Comment: https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#id9 states that the platform is Mac OS X only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python package installation issues: PyAudio, PortAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio)

Comment: It seems that [PyAudio on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/) hasn't been updated in a while, same thing on the webpage which @PNX shared.

Comment: instead of all this i can also use .whl file for installing pyaudio irrespective of my windows version......@AMC

Comment: my https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/ is already updated @AMC

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
brew install portaudio
```

Then:

```
brew link portaudio

pip install pyAudio
```

Or if you are using windows:

Go to: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Download the file and then go to its directory in the cmd and type:

For win 32 bit:

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```

For win 64 bit:

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Are you using windows? I added another way to my solution, which one did not work for you?

Comment: ERROR: PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl is not a valid wheel filename........this error comes out

Comment: If you are using win 64 please download 64 ones

Comment: For example: PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: the same issue for me: ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 2):

For windows-
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

press *ctrl + f* and search pyaudio and scroll down

Download any version of this if you are using 64 bit-

**PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl**

or download any version of this if you are using  32 bit -

**PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win32.whl**

go to the file location of the downloaded file and press *Shift + Right click*

**select open command window here**
then copy the file name and paste like pip install "file name" for e.g-

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on Ubunutu/Linux try below.
It worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
pip install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the pyAudio file manually and put it in a directory and cd to the same directory and run the given command.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is highly recommended to post text information as text not images.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it using `pipwin`:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```