# pip3 install pyaudio on mac os

Tags: macos, pyaudio

I'm trying to build a virtual assistant and need a good website to follow. I'm on a mac OS Catalina.

I was able to successfully install:

```
pip3 install gTTS
pip3 install SpeechRecognition
pip3 install pygame
```

However when I tried installing

```
pip3 install PyAudio
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Building wheel for PyAudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 while installing pyaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290821/error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-pyaudio)

Answer (score 0):

In macOS you need portaudio for [pyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) to work. Just install it using brew:

```
brew install portaudio
```