# Not able to install py audio: pip install pyaudio

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

**Not able to install py audio: pip install pyaudio**
using pycharm

now the error has changed to this, The module is listed (PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz) but then it returns an error (`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`):

```
(venv) C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\pythonproject2\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\
\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oygnlr22\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oygnlr22\\pyaudio\\setup.py'
"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"')
)' install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mnp5i0dx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\
users\admin\pycharmprojects\pythonproject2\venv\include\site\python3.9\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oygnlr22\pyaudio\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=
1 -Ic:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\pythonproject2\venv\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Progr
ams\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kit
s\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -
IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Window
s Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit c
ode 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\pythonproject2\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys
.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oygnlr22\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-ins
tall-oygnlr22\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compil
e(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mnp5i0dx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed
 --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\pythonproject2\venv\include\site\python3.9\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Are you using visual studio code?

Comment: no i am using pycharm

Comment: Is pip installed with your normal python install. When you install it there should be a option that says `Add Python (VERSION) to PATH`. Did you do this? If not try reinstalling the normal python (not pycharm) and add python to path

Comment: It reads like a network error! I am not sure why `getaddrinfo` would fail tho

Comment: If you look at the error "Failed to establish a new connection", it appears you cannot to the pypi website. Try to do "pip -v install pyaudio" to get more output to find out why it is not working. Are you for example behind a proxy?

Comment: @urban thanks for the edit I can see its a HTTPS error as well now. Would it be server sided? I doubt it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python package installation issues: PyAudio, PortAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio)

Answer (score 0):

First run your CMD as Administrator and run the following

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```