# Trouble with Pyaudio

Tags: python, pycharm, pyaudio

I am running:

```
pip install PyAudio
```

I get this output:

```
C:\Users\graymouse\PycharmProjects\EmailBot>pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyAudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\graymouse\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\graymouse\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
\\pip-install-q96wwkqf\\pyaudio_a5b98de520a84c63ad40636eaf059e91\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\graymouse\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q96wwkqf\\pyaudio_a5b98de520a84c63ad
40636eaf059e91\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'
))' install --record 'C:\Users\graymouse\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-064zortn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\graymouse\app
data\local\programs\python\python39\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\graymouse\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q96wwkqf\pyaudio_a5b98de520a84c63ad40636eaf059e91\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\graymouse\a
ppdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\graymouse\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools
\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\
Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_
portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\graymouse\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\graymouse\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users
\\graymouse\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q96wwkqf\\pyaudio_a5b98de520a84c63ad40636eaf059e91\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\graymouse\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q96
wwkqf\\pyaudio_a5b98de520a84c63ad40636eaf059e91\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compi
le(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\graymouse\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-064zortn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --instal
l-headers 'c:\users\graymouse\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio

Answer (score 0):

Go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) and download `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`

Then go to the folder where it is downloaded using `cd`

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```