# error in installing a module or package or something in python

Tags: python, module, fatal-error

I am trying to install pyaudio module in my terminal for python, and I got this error.

> rc/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
> file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
> error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe'
> failed with exit status 2

Help me please

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio), you might find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you are targeting native Win32 Python, you will need either MinGW (via Cygwin) or Microsoft Visual Studio

[pyaudio compilation docs](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/compilation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. pip install pipwin
2. pipwin install pyaudio

Comment: Thanks for helping me. it works and pyaudio is installed.