# cant instal pyaudio at VScode

Tags: python, windows, pip

trying to install pyaudio, already installed python3.9
searched for more information about install pyaudio in other ways - ex. download .whl file and install directly (isn't help - still receive an error)

edit:
I tried to do this: [Python package installation issues: PyAudio, PortAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio) = but doesn't help

also, I tried to install anaconda and then install pyaudio (success) but in VScode my code doesn't run because he don't finds pyaudio

I received this error:

```
C:\Users\cohen\Desktop>pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Building wheel for PyAudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\cohen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-etfwlxv9\\pyaudio_b4064b2323f546ffa7760cec69aadeb4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\cohen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-etfwlxv9\\pyaudio_b4064b2323f546ffa7760cec69aadeb4\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\cohen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-jv4qwbqa'
       cwd: C:\Users\cohen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-etfwlxv9\pyaudio_b4064b2323f546ffa7760cec69aadeb4\
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\program files\python39\include -Ic:\program files\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  c:\program files\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
  src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\cohen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-etfwlxv9\\pyaudio_b4064b2323f546ffa7760cec69aadeb4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\cohen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-etfwlxv9\\pyaudio_b4064b2323f546ffa7760cec69aadeb4\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\cohen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bc3svaom\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\program files\python39\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\cohen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-etfwlxv9\pyaudio_b4064b2323f546ffa7760cec69aadeb4\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\program files\python39\include -Ic:\program files\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\program files\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\cohen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-etfwlxv9\\pyaudio_b4064b2323f546ffa7760cec69aadeb4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\cohen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-etfwlxv9\\pyaudio_b4064b2323f546ffa7760cec69aadeb4\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\cohen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bc3svaom\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\program files\python39\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error when installing it directly via whl file?

Comment: You seem to be missing the PortAudio library. Maybe this older question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio

Comment: I tried to do this: Python package installation issues: PyAudio, PortAudio = but doesn't help

also, I tried to install anaconda and then install pyaudio (success) but in VScode my code doesn't run because he don't finds pyaudio