# I am trying to install py audio from power shell(vs code) and it is giving me this error

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am trying to install pyaudio from PowerShell(vscode) but I am getting error.

```
pip install pyaudio
```

I wrote the above code to install the library.

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) … error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\anurag\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Anurag\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3rsxjttk\\pyaudio_34a9923277384daebdb4a4802c27bd32\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Anurag\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3rsxjttk\\pyaudio_34a9923277384daebdb4a4802c27bd32\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Anurag\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-jbiq5gfw'
       cwd: C:\Users\Anurag\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rsxjttk\pyaudio_34a9923277384daebdb4a4802c27bd32\
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\anurag\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\anurag\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  c:\users\anurag\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
  src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/how-to-fix-installation-issues-for-pyaudio-portaudio-fatal-error-c1083-canno) to solve, it may help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix installation issues for PyAudio, PortAudio: "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/how-to-fix-installation-issues-for-pyaudio-portaudio-fatal-error-c1083-canno)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following 2 commands:

```
pip install pipwin
```

then

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```