# Trying to pip install module but getting ERROR

Tags: python

I'm trying to pip install `PyAudio` in a venv to use it in tandem with the `SpeechRecognition` module. Any chance you know a quick fix to my error message?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1
```

Or is this a deeper problem? And feel free to let me know if this is a stupid question! By the way, I've tried `pip install PyAudio` in my cmd as administrator, too. Same error. And I'm not too keen on downloading an older version of Python (I'm using 3.9.0) as some would suggest.

Here's my full error message, if that helps (I'm not sure what to look at, but you might):

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ethan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aydn66pc\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ethan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aydn66pc\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-otzyi04l\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aydn66pc\pyaudio\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ethan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aydn66pc\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ethan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aydn66pc\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-otzyi04l\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `ERROR` line says (at the end): _Check the logs for full command output_. What do the logs say?

Comment: The important part of the error message is "Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory". I suggest googling this to see if you can find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [portaudio.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690984/portaudio-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: So it seems like pyaudio doesnt support newer versions of python - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14

Comment: Yup - checking on the pyaudio site - https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/ - it only supports up to python 3.6

Comment: @Code-Apprentice hes on windows not ubuntu

Comment: There isn't an official binary on PyPI so `pip` is trying to compile from source. On Windows this is often less that straightforward. Your error message says it is missing a C header file `portaudio.h`. Probably because it can be expected to be present in a Linux installation. Follow the advice to download a Windows binary from Christop Gohlke's site.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to all these errors which occur with pip is that you manually download them
from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

procedure:

1. lets say you have installed it in your downloads folder , you have to open your terminal there using the `cd` command eg: cd Downloads/
2. then type `pip install <name of the .whl file>`

done this can be used for other modules too

Answer (score 0):

> pip install pipwin
>
> pipwin install pyaudio

Comment: While this commands may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.