# I can't install both Portaudio and pyaudio, on mac

Tags: python, homebrew

I tried to install pyaudio (pip install pyaudio) for my project, but

```
#include "portaudio.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

This error came out so I tried "brew install portaudio" but I couldn't install this one too with this error.

```
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "portaudio".
```

I've already done install / uninstall "Homebrew" for several time and it still does not work. Is there any solutions I can get out of this problem?

Comment: did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690984/portaudio-h-no-such-file-or-directory?