# Failure to Pip-Install PyAudio

Tags: python, terminal, pip, pycharm, pyaudio

I am attempting to make my own alexa or smart home interface and everytime I try to install PyAudio via the PyCharm terminal it comes up with this huge error. So can anyone decipher this and tell me how to solve it? I previously had this problem and it said I had to install Visual Studio Installer and install C++ I believe for Windows and it made some progress from where that crashed, but it still will not work:

```
PS C:\Users\rajan> pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\rajan\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\Lo
cal\\Temp\\pip-install-p4j0s73x\\pyaudio_4d566f10f0074bb997b5fa27c43139b5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p4j0s73x\\pyaudio_4
d566f10f0074bb997b5fa27c43139b5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import s
etup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local
\Temp\pip-wheel-ew2b872l'
       cwd: C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p4j0s73x\pyaudio_4d566f10f0074bb997b5fa27c43139b5\
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Users\r
ajan\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\include -IC:\Program Files\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildT
ools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared
-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\i
nclude\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  C:\Program Files\Python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
  src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\rajan\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\
Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p4j0s73x\\pyaudio_4d566f10f0074bb997b5fa27c43139b5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p4j0s73x\\pyaudio
_4d566f10f0074bb997b5fa27c43139b5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
 setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rajan\AppData\L
ocal\Temp\pip-record-n67t7h0p\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\rajan\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\include\site\py
thon3.9\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p4j0s73x\pyaudio_4d566f10f0074bb997b5fa27c43139b5\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Users
\rajan\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\include -IC:\Program Files\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Buil
dTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\share
d -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    C:\Program Files\Python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\rajan\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
 '"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p4j0s73x\\pyaudio_4d566f10f0074bb997b5fa27c43139b5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\Local\\Te
mp\\pip-install-p4j0s73x\\pyaudio_4d566f10f0074bb997b5fa27c43139b5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.Str
```

Comment: [Here is your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66379791/14976549)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [portaudio.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690984/portaudio-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Interesting I'll give those a go. Thanks! Out of interest, do you know what terminal means when it says 'consider adding this directory to PATH'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14)

Comment: That is the issue I initially had. Then I installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 and when I tried to install pyaudio, it progresses further but has failed on another point: something to do with the portaudio